# What does bashrc PS1 check [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] mean?

Tags: bash, bashrc

In bashrc file in Fedora/Red Hat I see following line:

```
[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

What is the check being done in `[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ]` and why is PS1 set only if the test succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\\s-\\v\\\$ "` is a default bash unprivileged prompt.

This line:

```
[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

change bash prompt only if it is set to default.

Some useful elements for bash prompt:

- `\s` - shell name
- `\v` - shell version
- `\u` - username
- `\h` - hostname
- `\t` - current time
- `\d` - current date
- `\W` - current directory